# problem using SSToolkit in iOS app

Tags: ios, sstoolkit

I am having some problem using the SSToolkit in my app. I have done everything mentioned at sstoolk.it for xcode 4.

The problem is, after adding the external library "libSSToolkit.a", it is shown in red colors (probably indicating missing file). Also, I get error that file/folder doesnot exist when I do :
    #import "SSToolkit/SSToolkit.h"

Any help, anyone ?

Comment: did you ever manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and by comparing my project with the settings in the SSCatalog project I discovered that SSCatalog also includes the QuartzCore framework. So I added QuartzCore.framework under Link Binary With Libraries in Build Phases and now it builds fine.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
#import <SSToolkit/SSToolkit.h>
```

once it is built, the static library should go black. I'm using parts of this in a current project, so it definitely works, but setup can be a bit tricky.

Comment: could you run through how you have set up SSToolkit? did you download the source, or add it as a git submodule? could you post a screen shot of the build phases of the active target? and also the header search paths in the build settings tab?

Answer (score -1):

There's also the bool `Always Search User Paths` in `Project Settings` > `Project` > `Build Settings`.